# `aws_secretsmanager_secret` Returns Correct Values When Hard Coded But Wrong Values From Original Variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

## Description

I'm hitting a weird issue while attempting to use `cyrilgdn/postgresql` Terraform provider on version `1.21.0`. If I hard code a secret ARN that's generated by `aws_db_instance` when using `manage_master_user_password` I correctly authenticate into the RDS instance and apply my changes.

When instead I attempt to reference the secret using `aws_db_instance.test_db.master_user_secret[0].secret_arn` (even though it's the same value when I look at it in `terraform console`) I instead find that the provider is attempt to log into the DB with a user that's not contained in the secrets manager secret.

I'm looking to understand what my underlying issue is OR a next step to help me debug what's going on here in detail.

## Error Message

```
│ Error: Error connecting to PostgreSQL server {rds_db_name}.{region}.rds.amazonaws.com (scheme: postgres): XXXXpXXXXq: password authentication failed for user "terraform"
│
│   with postgresql_extension.postgis,
│   on rds.tf line 135, in resource "postgresql_extension" "postgis":
│  135: resource "postgresql_extension" "postgis" {
```

the actual user name is `db_admin` here and that's the value contained in the Terraform generated secret.

If I hard code the secret ARN I don't get any authentication issues.

## Code In Question

```
  data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "master_user" {
    # There's some kind of race condition happening here. Need to drill into why
    # this isn't working as expected
    arn = aws_db_instance.test_db.master_user_secret[0].secret_arn
    # If I hard code the value that's contained in aws_db_instance.test_db.master_user_secret[0].secret_arn then I can get the correct username / password.
    #arn = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:{region}:{account_id}:secret:rds!{secret_id}"
  }

  data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "master_user" {
    secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.master_user.id
  }

  provider "postgresql" {
    host             = aws_db_instance.test_db.address
    username         = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.master_user.secret_string)["username"]
    password         = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.master_user.secret_string)["password"]
    expected_version = "16.2"
    sslmode          = "require"
    connect_timeout  = 15
  }

  resource "postgresql_extension" "postgis" {
    name = "postgis"
  }
```

## Manual Verification

Using

```
nonsensitive(jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.master_user.secret_string))
```

I've been able to confirm that the username and password are correct in `terraform console`.

So I'm pretty confused as to what's happening here.

## EDIT: Tried Referencing By Name

This leads to the same behavior so at least what's happening is consistent. =P

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "master_user" {
    name = reverse(split(":", aws_db_instance.test_db.master_user_secret[0].secret_arn))[0]
}
```

## Edit Two: Provider Details At Runtime

I'm sitting over here wondering if I have a bootstrapping problem. Maybe Terraform is too accepting of my setup and in my case the configuration is invalid. Specifically

```
  provider "postgresql" {
    host             = aws_db_instance.test_db.address
    username         = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.master_user.secret_string)["username"]
    password         = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.master_user.secret_string)["password"]
    expected_version = "16.2"
    sslmode          = "require"
    connect_timeout  = 15
  }
```

being dependent on the RDS instance being created and building secret. Basically, I'm wondering if Terraform isn't dynamic enough to be able to handle building a provider on values that will be defined after an apply and it doesn't throw an error for my particular case when it should do so.

## Edit Three

Pretty sure I'm running into this issue and I don't understand why my plans and applys are working at all

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24476

## Edit Four: aws_db_instance

```
resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "test_db" {
  name   = "test-db-${var.env_name}"
  family = "postgres16"

  parameter {
    name         = "shared_preload_libraries"
    value        = "pg_cron"
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "test_db" {
  db_name        = local.db_name
  identifier     = local.db_identifier
  engine         = "postgres"
  engine_version = "16.2"
  instance_class = "db.t3.xlarge"
  backup_retention_period = 0
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.test_db.name
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["postgresql", "upgrade"]
  allocated_storage = 200
  max_allocated_storage = 300
  apply_immediately = false
  availability_zone = var.db_region
  manage_master_user_password   = true
  master_user_secret_kms_key_id = aws_kms_key.test_db.key_id
  username                      = "db_admin"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.test_db.id]
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
  parameter_group_name = aws_db_parameter_group.test_db.name
  iam_database_authentication_enabled = true
}
```

Comment: That last link `Ability to pass providers to modules in for_each` that is about modules but your sample code does not talk about anything modules

Comment: Can you share the TF code of your `aws_db_instance`

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I've added my `aws_db_instance` declaration and the parameter group I'm using since that's will be required if you wanted to locally test.

Comment: @AlexLordThorsen - Did you get to the bottom of this. I am running into exactly the same problem when using the `postgresql` provider. Credentials checked confirmed and working, but within TF I get a SSL is not enabled error, though changing SSL settings makes no difference.

Comment: No, I never did figure out the why for this one. I ended up splitting my Terraform repo into a "resources" module and a "provisioning" module because I've hit this with other resources with self managed secrets as well. I don't love having to run apply twice because it breaks my ideal for a "push button" solution but I needed to move on at a certain point.